# Custom 404 page when Next.js rewrites' origin responds with 404

Tags: next.js

I have a Next.js app with rewrites config. The destination is external url.

```js
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/foo/:slug',
        destination: 'https://example.com/foo/:slug',
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

Is there any way to render custom 404 page when the origin server returns 404?
Currently my app renders what the origin server returns as-is, although I have pages/404.tsx.

Answer (score 0):

You can make same functionality in middleware.tsx

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/matcher-url'],
};
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL('/rewrite-url', request.url));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all your rewrites in a middleware (like prev. answer mentioned), you better separate concerns, let your rewrites in the `next.config.js` and write a middleware only to prefetch and handle not found (or even errored if you want) rewritten pages.

Example:

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/foo/:slug'
    // any other path you want to check
  ],
}

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const check = await fetch(request.url, { method: 'HEAD' })
  if (!check.ok)
    return NextResponse.rewrite(
      new URL(
        "/404", // or the path of your not found page
      ),
    )
  return NextResponse.next()
}
```